# Why does the Google Sheets SUM function applied to a range that includes times and text return a decimal number

Tags: google-sheets, time, sum, google-sheets-formula, duration

Why does the following use of `SUM` not give the correct answer:

[image: Example]

The `SUM` function on a piece of text returns `0`, so why would `SUM(D:D)` ever return a decimal number. The `SUM` function doesn't have this problem when dealing with plain numbers. As expected `SUM(E1)+SUM(D2:D)` does return the correct answer.

What is the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date/time objects in Spreadsheets are calculated considering that each day counts as 1, each hour as 1/24, each minute as 1/(24*60), and so on...

You can sum time objects and use time formatting in that cell OR convert to a unit that makes sense to you. Ex: if you need to see how many hours, just multiply that SUM by 24. (Please note that this method will turn hour into decimal number, making `01:30:00 -> 1,5`)

**NOTE:** when you input only time, its still a date/time object on day zero of the calendar. Check this link: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/10/12/date-time-google-sheets/

Answer (score 1):

the answer is correct. it returns timevalue.

use this formula for duration:

```
=TEXT(SUM(D2:D); "[hh]:mm")
```

[image]

Comment: I've upvoted your answer. I accepted @Bruno Polo's answer because of the explanation about Date/Time objects.